# C# Customizing the title bar of a GUI Window

Tags: c#, user-interface, gtk#, platform-independent

I am using C# and want to create a GUI. 
I want to make a platform independend application, so I need a platform independent toolkit. Right now I am using gtk sharp 2.0, though I have not done much with it. 
I know this question is asked quite a few times, but not really for a platform independend gui toolkit. Even using gtk# the window is still native ( the look of my Windows ). So I thought of setting the decoration to false. This way there is no windows title bar/border and I could make my own out of gtk#'s gui elements. BUT then I also need todo resizing and moving of the application, though I guess this can somehow be managed with events, resizing with a button is easy I guess, but at the edge of the app, I guess it's more difficult to code that.

Also with decoration set to false, the application is no longer minimized, when clicking on it in the taskbar. Is there a way to achieve this again? Maybe some native api call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there, I'm not sure what your question is? You're right I think about needing to implement the window move, resize etc. yourself. Regarding minimisation on the task bar, bear in mind that anything native will mean your code would need to account for different platforms itself which kinda defeats the reason why you're doing cross-platform in the first place?